# How to create a string or char from an ASCII value in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, ascii

In JavaScript, how to get a string representation of an ASCII value, e.g. how to turn `65` into `A`?

Comment: you may mark his answer as correct. There's a little check right below the downvote arrow.

Comment: See also: [How to convert from Hex to ASCII in javascript?][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3745666/how-to-convert-from-hex-to-ascii-in-javascript

Answer (score 122):

The [fromCharCode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCharCode) method converts ASCII to a string:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.write(String.fromCharCode(65,66,67)); // ABC
</script>
```

Comment: See also [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCharCode).

Answer (score 10):

[A reference for those of us that don't like w3schools ;)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCharCode)

Usage:

`var myAString = String.fromCharCode(65)`

Answer (score 3):

The method you're looking for is String.fromCharCode (http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_fromCharCode.asp).

Answer (score -1):

`charCodeAt()` method can be used to get the ASCII value.

Comment: The question asks the other way.