# How to convert from Hex to ASCII in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

How to convert from `Hex` string to `ASCII` string in JavaScript?

Ex:

> 32343630 it will be 2460

Comment: I'm sure there's a jQuery plugin for that ^^

Comment: jQuery is primarily meant for DOM manipulation and to a lesser extent, reimplementing things like `Array.prototype.{map,forEach}()` for outdated/limited browsers. Honestly this seems more like [Underscore.js's](http://underscorejs.org/) realm.

Comment: @AndiDog Not useful for those of us using node

Answer (score 192, accepted):

```
function hex2a(hexx) {
    var hex = hexx.toString();//force conversion
    var str = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < hex.length; i += 2)
        str += String.fromCharCode(parseInt(hex.substr(i, 2), 16));
    return str;
}
hex2a('32343630'); // returns '2460'
```

Comment: This does not work. `console.log(hex2a('32343630') === hex2a('3234363000')); // returns 'true'!!!`.

Comment: This answer is wrong due to: `&& hex.substr(i, 2) !== '00'`. As @steinybot noticed, this aborts on the first `0` and therefore does not completely convert hex to string.

The correct solution is:

`function hex2a(hexx) {
    var hex = hexx.toString();//force conversion
    var str = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < hex.length; i += 2)
        str += String.fromCharCode(parseInt(hex.substr(i, 2), 16));
    return str;
}`

Comment: The [edit history](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/19350946) shows that the `NUL` defect was added on purpose. This answer has been damaged.

Comment: Hey I did the same thing but unfortunately. I am stuck with a problem. The first 2 characters are read and added to the str. But Something happens in the third character and no more character could be added to the string. 

I logged the iteration and see something like this
i:1 M
i:2 MZ
i:3 MZDCS
i:4 MZDCS
This DCS is a black boxed character in Notepad++

Answer (score 52):

Another way to do it (if you use Node.js):

```
var input  = '32343630';
const output = Buffer.from(input, 'hex');
log(input + " -> " + output);  // Result: 32343630 -> 2460
```

Comment: Best solution! Using native functions. This should be the accepted answer!

Comment: to then convert ```output``` to ASCII, use ```output.toString()```

Comment: `new Buffer(input,"hex").toString()` gives out the original string

Answer (score 39):

For completeness sake the reverse function:

```
function a2hex(str) {
  var arr = [];
  for (var i = 0, l = str.length; i < l; i ++) {
    var hex = Number(str.charCodeAt(i)).toString(16);
    arr.push(hex);
  }
  return arr.join('');
}
a2hex('2460'); //returns 32343630
```

Comment: A note on this implementation: you must manually insert a "0" when the `hex` value is between 0x0 and 0x9. For this, I change your `arr.push(hex)` to `arr.push(hex.length > 1 && hex || "0" + hex);`.

Comment: String concatenation is actually faster than string array construction and joining in javascript

Comment: You have a typo, you forgot to put the closing parenthesis after `toString(16)` (line no. 4). ;-)

Answer (score 28):

You can use this..

```js
var asciiVal = "32343630".match(/.{1,2}/g).map(function(v){
      return String.fromCharCode(parseInt(v, 16));
    }).join('');
    
document.write(asciiVal);
```

Answer (score 13):

** for Hexa to String**

```
let input  = '32343630';
```

Note : let output = new Buffer(input, 'hex');  // this is deprecated

```
let buf = Buffer.from(input, "hex");
let data = buf.toString("utf8");
```

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted, seems to me that's the best answer now for nodejs in 2020

Comment: @PascalBelloncle I agree that this is the best answer for Node.js but the problem is that `Buffer` doesn't exist in regular JavaScript. I expect the downvote was because the question is tagged with JavaScript and not Node.js.

Comment: What do you mean it does not exist in regular JS @DonCruickshank

Comment: @DanielTkach By regular JavaScript I meant common browsers. `Buffer.from("414243", "hex")` works on Node.js but it fails on Edge and Firefox as `Buffer` is not defined.

Answer (score 10):

I found a useful function present in [web3](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3toascii) library.

```
var hexString = "0x1231ac"
string strValue = web3.toAscii(hexString)
```

**Update:** Newer version of web3 has this function in utils

The functions now resides in utils:

```
var hexString = "0x1231ac"
string strValue = web3.utils.hexToAscii(hexString)
```

Comment: The function is now called `web3.utils.hexToAscii(hexString)` in v1.2.9
https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.9/web3-utils.html?highlight=ascii#hextoascii

Comment: Thank you, best answer for blockchain devs

Answer (score 5):

```js
console.log(

"68656c6c6f20776f726c6421".match(/.{1,2}/g).reduce((acc,char)=>acc+String.fromCharCode(parseInt(char, 16)),"")

)
```

Answer (score 3):

I've found that the above solution will not work if you have to deal with control characters like `02` (STX) or `03` (ETX), anything under `10` will be read as a single digit and throw off everything after. I ran into this problem trying to parse through serial communications. So, I first took the hex string received and put it in a buffer object then converted the hex string into an array of the strings like so:

```js
buf = Buffer.from(data, 'hex');
l = Buffer.byteLength(buf,'hex');
for (i=0; i<l; i++){

    char = buf.toString('hex', i, i+1);
    msgArray.push(char);

}
```

Then .join it

```js
message = msgArray.join('');
```

then I created a `hexToAscii` function just like in **@Delan Azabani's** answer above...

```js
function hexToAscii(str){
    hexString = str;
    strOut = '';
        for (x = 0; x < hexString.length; x += 2) {
            strOut += String.fromCharCode(parseInt(hexString.substr(x, 2), 16));
        }
    return strOut;    
}
```

then called the `hexToAscii` function on 'message'

```js
message = hexToAscii(message);
```

This approach also allowed me to iterate through the array and slice into the different parts of the transmission using the control characters so I could then deal with only the part of the data I wanted.
Hope this helps someone else!

Answer (score 1):

An optimized version of the implementation of the reverse function proposed by @michieljoris (according to the comments of @Beterraba and @Mala):

```js
function a2hex(str) {
  var hex = '';
  for (var i = 0, l = str.length; i < l; i++) {
    var hexx = Number(str.charCodeAt(i)).toString(16);
    hex += (hexx.length > 1 && hexx || '0' + hexx);
  }
  return hex;
}
alert(a2hex('2460')); // display 32343630
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this one, it seems more clear to me as I also receive data with spaces like '30 31 38 30 38 30' and the output is 018080

```
hexToString(hex: string): string {
   return hex.split(' ').map(s => string.fromCharCode(parseInt(s,16))).join('');
}
```

Comment: But the question is not about input in this form (with spaces)...

Comment: I guess there is already a right answer, and that’s why I mentioned input and output instead of just a solution