# Javascript replace hex based on unique identifier

Tags: javascript, regex, hex, ascii

How can I take a string like

```
John, Smith~2C John, Jones~2CMike
```

And replace these hex values indicated by ~ with their ASCII counterparts?

Comment: A hint: [How to convert from Hex to ASCII in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3745666/how-to-convert-from-hex-to-ascii-in-javascript).

Comment: I`ve been using the functions above, but how can I efficiently go through a string without constantly cutting the hex part out and replacing it in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you always have 2 char hex-codes preceded by char `~`, then `/~[0-9A-F]{2}/i` will give a match.
Now if we match globally and attach a function to replace, we can parse the integer using radix/base 16 and generate a character (using Object String's method `fromCharCode`) from that. Just don't forget to strip the trailing `~` character first.

Here is a short example to get you started:

```
function demo(s){
  return s.replace(/~[0-9A-F]{2}/gi, function(m){
    return String.fromCharCode(parseInt(m.slice(1), 16));
  });
}

console.log( demo('John, Smith~2C John, Jones~2CMike')  );
```

Hope this helps!