# Generate Base64 MD5 hash of byte array

Tags: javascript, c#, hash, md5, asciiencoding

I have following security encoding implemented in my c# web api:

```
string testStr = "test";
ASCIIEncoding encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();    //using System.Text;
byte[] byteData = encoding.GetBytes(testStr);

MD5 md5 = MD5.Create();    //using System.Security.Cryptography;
string hash = md5.ComputeHash(byteData);
string md5Base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(hash);
```

I bind this `md5Base64` string in header and compare it in API request. This works fine when I hit the API from C# code. Now I need to use it in javascript, so will need js equivalent of above code.

I have tried following but it is giving different output:

```
var testStr = 'test';
var byteData = testStr.split ('').map(function (c) { return c.charCodeAt (0); });
var hash = MD5(value.join(','));
var md5Base64 = btoa(hash);
```

the `MD5` function used here is from https://stackoverflow.com/a/33486055/7519287

Please let me know what is wrong here.

Comment: I would not rely on a 1k rep user if its about cryptography. CryptoJS is a well known and actively maintained repo that does the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your JavaScript code is that you're doing unnecessary conversions: `MD5` already takes a string. Furthermore, more conversions after hashing are required.

If we have the following C# code:

```
string tmp = "test";
byte[] bTmp = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(tmp);
byte[] hashed = null;
using (System.Security.Cryptography.MD5CryptoServiceProvider md5 = new System.Security.Cryptography.MD5CryptoServiceProvider())
{
    hashed = md5.ComputeHash(bTmp);
}

Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToBase64String(hashed));
```

[Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/4msRzR)

then the equivalent JavaScript code is:

```
var tmp = 'test';
var hashed = hex2a(MD5(tmp)); // md5 src: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33486055/7519287

// src: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3745677/3181933
function hex2a(hexx) {
    var hex = hexx.toString();//force conversion
    var str = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < hex.length; i += 2)
        str += String.fromCharCode(parseInt(hex.substr(i, 2), 16));
    return str;
}

alert(btoa(hashed));
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dbvmdxma/1/)

Because MD5 returns a hex string, you have to convert that to ASCII before you can base64 encode it. I wonder if you need base64 encoding? MD5 is usually represented as a hex string. Perhaps on the C# side, instead of `Convert.ToBase64String(hashed)`, you could use `BitConverter.ToString(hashed).Replace("-", "")` to get a hex string for the MD5 hash? Then you could simply just use `MD5(tmp)` in JavaScript.

Comment: Can not change base64 encoding now as it is already being used at several places.