# Convert unicode to Chinese characters

Tags: javascript, character-encoding

Supposing I have a string of code like so:

`\u00e5\u00b1\u00b1\u00e4\u00b8\u008a\u00e7\u009a\u0084\u00e4\u00ba\u00ba`

How would I convert these back into Chinese characters using Javascript:

`山上的人`

This is so that I can actually display Chinese on  my web page. Right now it comes out as `å±±ä¸çäºº`.

[This website](http://ddecode.com/hexdecoder/) manages to accomplish this, however this is with PHP they don't expose.

I am not familiar with how character encoding works well at all, so I don't even know the terminology to search for a proper solution.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3745666/how-to-convert-from-hex-to-ascii-in-javascript

Comment: The code from that post doesn't do the trick.

Comment: Ah perhaps this one is more relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21647928/javascript-unicode-string-to-hex

Comment: That makes it come out as `å±±ä¸çäºº` in the browser. I'm trying to get this unicode to render on the page as Chinese.

Comment: @dthree—that is result of literal conversion of control code (\u00e5) to code point (229) to character (å).

Comment: JavaScript internally only works with UCS-2 (where 山 is `\u5C71`), and doesn't understand UTF-8 (`\xE5\xB1\xB1`). Moreover, `\u00e5\u00b1\u00b1` is likely wrong due to extra zeroes, probably. Thus it would be good to give it data in the proper form in the first place, rather than try to transform it (but if you absolutely need to do that, Steven Tang's answer seems to be good). Where is your data coming from?

Comment: @Amadan thanks. Yes, Steven's answer worked. Unfortunately I can't change the source data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The string appears to be in UTF-8.

https://github.com/mathiasbynens/utf8.js is a helpful Javascript library that saves you the headache of learning the UTF-8 standard, and will decode the UTF-8 into text.

Here's a demo: https://mothereff.in/utf-8

Paste in `\u00e5\u00b1\u00b1\u00e4\u00b8\u008a\u00e7\u009a\u0084\u00e4\u00ba\u00ba` into the "UTF-8-encoded" textarea to decode it.

Answer (score -1):

Add `<meta charset="UTF-8">` inside the `<head></head>` tag of your HTML file so that it will display Chinese properly. Just put the Chinese characters directly in your HTML file