# cryptoJS AES encrypt returning a wrong decryption

Tags: encryption, aes, cryptojs

```
console.log("user id to encrypt: "+user.id) //user id to encrypt: 0
    crypted_uId = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(user.id.toString(), 'pass123');
    console.log("encrypted uid on login: "+crypted_uId); //U2FsdGVkX1+senN8M0jydYxQKZVsu/+m3Qs/wvesnoM=
    decrypted_uId = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(crypted_uId, 'pass123');
    console.log("decrypted uid on login: "+decrypted_uId); //30
```

Whats wrong? Why is it returning an unproper decryption?

Comment: by the way, 30 is hex representation of "0" symbol. try to encrypt 12345 and see whether you will get 3132333435 back.

Comment: @MaximSagaydachny you are right , this seems to be my issue, I should recode it from hex to whatever i need to use

Comment: @MaximSagaydachny I dont actually know how to reconvert it back to a normal number. Do you know how to do it in thiscase?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3745666/how-to-convert-from-hex-to-ascii-in-javascript  Found the answer