# How do I make the same SHA256 encoded string in Javascript that I do in Python 3?

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, python-3.x, cryptography

I have this Python script which produces the correct output:

```py
import hashlib

username = "LoginUser"
password = "LoginPass"
nonce = "1234567890"

def LowerCase(s): return s.lower()
def Hex(s): return ''.join([hex(char)[2:] for char in s])

def SHA1(s): h = hashlib.sha1(); h.update(s); return h.digest()
def SHA1Raw(s): h = hashlib.sha1(); h.update(s); return h.hexdigest()

def SHA256(s): h = hashlib.sha256(); h.update(s); return h.digest()
def SHA256Raw(s): h = hashlib.sha256(); h.update(s); return h.hexdigest()

def UTF8Encode(s): return str.encode(s)



step1 = SHA256((UTF8Encode(username)))
step2 = SHA1((UTF8Encode(password)))

step3 = SHA256Raw(step1 + step2)

step1 = SHA256Raw((UTF8Encode(username)))
step2 = SHA1Raw((UTF8Encode(password)))


print("""
SHA256(username={username})                            =    {step1}
SHA1(password={password})                              =    {step2}
SHA256((username + password)={username}{password})     =    {step3}
""".format(
    username = username,
    password = password,
    step1 = step1,
    step2 = step2,
    step3 = step3
))
```

Output:

```
PS D:\project> python .\test.py
SHA256(username=LoginUser)                            =    7981673b2c73a6bdb665f347dc89e9d324f542b1fa1c4a700bc523d8a9a6f565  
SHA1(password=LoginPass)                              =    df703733447469593d39a125ca93462eade53cab
SHA256((username + password)=LoginUserLoginPass)     =    cf3066e157468d6a9d59f9ff0662e4f8f8432be4e07c68320a8b6a031d0c022b
```

Now in Javascript, I try to mirror the functions I have in Python. I cannot for the life of me. I tried quickly understanding Buffers and streams in this context but I believe I am just confusing myself further by not staying grounded to something.

Anyways here's the Javascript versiona and it's output:

```js
const crypto = require('crypto')

const username = "LoginUser"
const password = "LoginPass"
const nonce = "1234567890"

const LowerCase = s => s.toLowerCase()
const Hex = s => Buffer.from(s, 'utf8').toString('hex')

const SHA1 = s => crypto.createHash('sha1').update(s, 'utf8').digest('hex')
const SHA1Raw = s => crypto.createHash('sha1').update(s, 'utf8').digest()

const SHA256 = s => crypto.createHash('sha256').update(s, 'utf8').digest('hex')
const SHA256Raw = s => crypto.createHash('sha256').update(s, 'utf8').digest()

const UTF8Encode = s => Buffer.from(s, 'utf8');


let step1 = SHA256(username)
let step2 = SHA1(password)
let step3 = SHA256Raw(step1.concat(step2))

console.log(`
SHA256(username=${username})                            =    ${step1}
SHA1(password=${password})                              =    ${step2}
SHA256((username + password)=${username+password})      =    ${step3.toString('hex')}
`)
```

Output:

```
PS D:\project> node .\test.js


SHA256(username=LoginUser)                            =    7981673b2c73a6bdb665f347dc89e9d324f542b1fa1c4a700bc523d8a9a6f565
SHA1(password=LoginPass)                              =    df703733447469593d39a125ca93462eade53cab
SHA256((username + password)=LoginUserLoginPass)      =    757101f0fd2628ce12dc039146f56da14a1e85a27fda5d68c2623f616c4fc3cc
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Whatever you're doing, don't save passwords like that. Use proper password hashing functions like Argon2.

Comment: This was the first 3 stages of 5 to hash a password for a 3rd party API AuthenticationRequest

Comment: You appear to be getting your raw and hex-encoded hashes in a muddle. `757101f0fd2628ce12dc039146f56da14a1e85a27fda5d68c2623f616c4fc3cc` is the sha256 hash of the hex string `7981673b2c73a6bdb665f347dc89e9d324f542b1fa1c4a700bc523d8a9a6f565` + `df703733447469593d39a125ca93462eade53cab`. Your Python code is calculating the hash of the corresponding byte array [0x79, 0x81, 0x67, 0x2c, 0x73, 0xa6, ...etc...]

Comment: @r3mainer how would I calculate the hash of a byte array in javascript? I tried creating a buffer and looping through it to update a hash but that has given me the same output.

Comment: Why don't you just [convert the hex data to a string of bytes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3745666/1679849) before calculating the hash?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only need a very small modification to make this work in Node.js.

I would suggest calculating the hashes as buffer objects, this makes the combined hash easier to calculate (since we don't need to parse from hex).

We do this by using [Buffer.concat](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_class_method_buffer_concat_list_totallength) to concatenate the output of the previous hashes.

```
const crypto = require('crypto')

const username = "LoginUser"
const password = "LoginPass"
const nonce = "1234567890"

const LowerCase = s => s.toLowerCase()
const Hex = s => Buffer.from(s, 'utf8').toString('hex')

const SHA1 = s => crypto.createHash('sha1').update(s, 'utf8').digest('hex')
const SHA1Raw = s => crypto.createHash('sha1').update(s, 'utf8').digest()

const SHA256 = s => crypto.createHash('sha256').update(s, 'utf8').digest('hex')
const SHA256Raw = s => crypto.createHash('sha256').update(s, 'utf8').digest()

const UTF8Encode = s => Buffer.from(s, 'utf8');


let step1 = SHA256Raw(username) // Get the SHA256 as a buffer.
let step2 = SHA1Raw(password) // Get the SHA1 as a buffer.
let step3 = SHA256Raw(Buffer.concat([step1, step2])) // Get the SHA256 of the previous steps concatenated as a buffer.

console.log(`
SHA256(username=${username})                            =    ${step1.toString('hex')}
SHA1(password=${password})                              =    ${step2.toString('hex')}
SHA256((username + password)=${username+password})      =    ${step3.toString('hex')}
`)
```

This gives the correct result, e.g.

```
SHA256(username=LoginUser)                            =    7981673b2c73a6bdb665f347dc89e9d324f542b1fa1c4a700bc523d8a9a6f565
SHA1(password=LoginPass)                              =    df703733447469593d39a125ca93462eade53cab
SHA256((username + password)=LoginUserLoginPass)      =    cf3066e157468d6a9d59f9ff0662e4f8f8432be4e07c68320a8b6a031d0c022b
```

Comment: Thank you! Works flawlessly. I tried the aforementioned method of converting the step1+2 strings into byte arrays but I got malformed results. I suppose I didn't forsee the Buffer.concat() method being the solution here. Again, I give my biggest thanks. I'll read up on the Buffer type in Javascript and try to see what's happening here in more clear terms. Parsing from hex seems to be a redundant/unnecessary step, so I'll have to develop my understanding of why it is.

Comment: Great to hear it, Python seems to handle concatenation a little bit more seamlessly. It's a real Node thing the Buffer.concat. In any case it's a small change, but yes it can be frustrating trying to find that last line of code!