# convert number to letter javascript

Tags: javascript, implicit-conversion

I'm trying to convert numbers into letters.  I'm making an array of divs that either need a number or a number and letter.  so 1-3 are just 1-3.  but 4-13 need to be a/4, b/5, c6 and so on.  is there a way I can converts these numbers into letter easily.  maybe changing the ascii values by a set amount?

```
     for(var i = 1; i < 33; i++){
    if( i < 4 || (i > 13 && i < 20) || i > 29){
        $('#teeth-diagram').append("<div class='tooth' id='" + i + "'>&nbsp;</div>");
    }else{
        $('#teeth-diagram').append("<div class='tooth' id='" + Letter goes here + "/" + i + "'>&nbsp;</div>");
    }
}
```

Comment: I think I'm missunderstood.  I don't want to type in a, b, c, d on each div.  I just want it to be done dynamically.  so if I can convert 4 in to a and 5 in to b that would be great

Comment: This one should be helpful - [create string or char from an ascii value][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/602020/javascript-create-a-string-or-char-from-an-ascii-value

Comment: @lserni Not without something like http://jalaj.net/2007/03/08/asc-and-chr-in-javascript/ ...what are `ord` and `chr` in javascript?

Comment: Sorry @Ian, I have them as shortcuts and often forget they're not standard. I had edited my comment, but too late :-)

Answer (score 56, accepted):

since 97 is the ascii value for 'a', and your value for 'a' is 3, you need to do this to get the value of the integer converted to a character:

```
if(i>=3){
    String.fromCharCode(94 + i);
}
```

Answer (score 29):

Yes, you can. Use `var letter = String.fromCharCode(number);`
To get a lowercase a, the number would be 97, b would be 98 and so forth. For uppercase A 65, B would be 66 and so forth.
See this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RZXDz/) for an example

Answer (score 7):

You can use the `String.fromCharCode(x)` function for this, you just need
to pass the proper index (eg: *97 = a, 98 = b*)

```js
const numberA = 1; // 1 = A, 2 = B,...., 26 = Z
const numberB = 2; 


//lowercase (start in CharCode 97)
console.log( String.fromCharCode(96 + numberA) ); //a
console.log( String.fromCharCode(96 + numberB) ); //b
   

console.log("------------");


//uppercase (start in CharCode 65)
console.log( String.fromCharCode(64 + numberA) ); //A
console.log( String.fromCharCode(64 + numberB) ); //B
```

Comment: For uppercase I would recommend just using the starting point of 64 instead of 96.  For me I use this: 


`//Index is base 0 so I use 65.
getLetter(index: number): string {
    // String.fromCharCode(65) returns (capital) A.  The next 26 chars is the subsequent letter.
    return String.fromCharCode(65 + index);
  }`

Comment: Note: 64 and 96 are NOT alphabet characters. So if you're using base 0, start at 65 and 97