# JavaScript: Assigning values to array of null/empty objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, for-loop, javascript-objects

I know the syntax is wrong, but in the following code `key` is supposed to equal the object's key. As the loop iterates, `key` gets assigned the `i` value, so `a:1`, `b:2`...etc.

```
var objArr = [
  {a: null},
  {b: null},
  {c: null}
];

for (var i = 0; i < objArr.length; i++) {
    objArr[i].key = i;
}
```

Comment: did you forget to put a semi-colon on your declaration?

Comment: @AlexisVillar that's valid JavaScript.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @clabe45 I really didn't try anything since I had no idea how to even approach this.

Comment: Think about your problem. You want to assign an incrementing number to a corresponding letter in the array of objects. You're on the right track, but you're setting the `key` property of each object. One way is to [convert the integer to a letter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13202079/3783155).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get the value of an object with an unknown single key in JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32208902/get-the-value-of-an-object-with-an-unknown-single-key-in-js)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the objects only contain one key, you can find the key using `Object.keys[0]`:

```js
var objArr = [
  {a: null},
  {b: null},
  {c: null}
];
objArr.forEach((obj, i) => {
  const key = Object.keys(obj)[0];
  obj[key] = i;
});
console.log(objArr);
```