# How do I get a letter of the alphabet by its position?

Tags: javascript, node.js, grid-layout

I'm trying to get the name of a field on a map (C12, B0, H5...).

I know where my target is (12th row, 5th column), but how do I turn the 5th column into E and end up with E12?

Comment: `String.fromCharCode('A'.charCodeAt(0) + row - 1)`

Comment: @Barmar How about AB31?

Comment: You'll need to check if the row number is higher than 26, then get the quotient and remainder to make multi-letter rows. But once you have each part, you still use the same formula to turn it into a letter.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [convert number to letter javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13201994/convert-number-to-letter-javascript)