# Binary concatenation

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have following code:

```
var packet = "\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF";
packet += "\x6D";
packet += "127.0.0.1:" + this.port;
packet += "\x00";
packet += this.name;
packet += "\x00";
packet += this.state;
packet += "\x00";
packet += "stateA";
packet += "\x00";
packet += "sender";
packet += "\x00";
```

And I have `var id = 32;`

I want to get something like this:

```
...
packet += "\x00";
packet += "sender";
packet += "\x00";
packet += "\x20;
```

How to convert `id` number to HEX format and then concatenate it with `packet`?

I already saw Google, but I haven't found a solution.

Thank you.

Comment: [How to convert decimal to hex in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/a/57805/1053938)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to convert decimal to hex in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/57803/how-to-convert-decimal-to-hex-in-javascript)

Comment: Why are you using strings and not buffers?

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript: create a string or char from an ASCII value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/602020/javascript-create-a-string-or-char-from-an-ascii-value)

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum I'm creating buffers from string.

Comment: @WasimAbu-Nassar why are you not writing into the buffer directly? Strings are immutable, every time you do `+=` you're destroying and creating a string. Also, (id+"").toString(16)

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum can you share a small example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [`toString()` function of the `Number` prototype](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toString) to get the hex representation of your number:

```
var hex = (23).toString( 16 );

// or

var hex = id.toString( 16 );
```

**EDIT**

It seems you just want to add a unicode symbol identified by `id`. For this use [`String.fromCharCode()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCharCode)

```
packet += String.fromCharCode( id );
```

Comment: I've already done this, but:
`packet += "\\x" + id.toString(16);`
Doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`String.fromCharCode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCharCode) function:

```
packet += String.fromCharCode(32); // " "
```

If you want to get the hex representation, you could use

```
var hex = (32).toString(16), // "20"
    byte = JSON.parse('"\\u'+('000'+hex).slice(-4)+'"'); // " " == "\u0020"
```

…but that's ugly :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `String.fromCharCode(23)` to do this.

E.G. (in a browser console):

```
> String.fromCharCode(23) == "\x17"
true
```

See [How to create a string or char from an ASCII value in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/602020/javascript-create-a-string-or-char-from-an-ascii-value) for more general information.