# Binary to String in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, binary

I have created a JavaScript program to convert a string into binary.

```
Input: StackOverflow
Output: 1010011 1110100 1100001 1100011 1101011 
1001111 1110110 1100101 1110010 1100110 
1101100 1101111 1110111
```

Now I want to convert that binary back into a string like below. Is there any possible way of doing this?

```
Input: 1010011 1110100 1100001 1100011 1101011 
1001111 1110110 1100101 1110010 1100110 
1101100 1101111 1110111 

Output StackOverflow
```

Thanks

Comment: You may check the solution over here: [Covert binary to text using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21354235/converting-binary-to-text-using-javascript/21354328)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21354235/converting-binary-to-text-using-javascript/21354328

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Use [`String.fromCharCode()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCharCode) and [`parseInt( , 2)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) like this:

```js
const binary = `1010011 1110100 1100001 1100011 1101011 
1001111 1110110 1100101 1110010 1100110 
1101100 1101111 1110111`;

const outputStr = binary
  // split string into an array of base 2 (binary) UTF-16 chars
  .split(' ')
  // map every binary char to a UTF-16 number of base 10
  // and then get the string representation of that UTF-16 number
  .map(bin => String.fromCharCode(parseInt(bin, 2)))
  // join the array back to a single string
  .join('');

console.log(outputStr);
```

- `String.fromCharCode(number)` will return a String from a UTF-16 char code
- `parseInt(binary , 2)` will transform a base 2 *number* string into a base 10 number

#### Edit:

As the `String.fromCharCode()` function accepts multiple chars as parameters, you could also use the [Spread Operator (`...`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) like so:

```js
const binary = `1010011 1110100 1100001 1100011 1101011 
1001111 1110110 1100101 1110010 1100110 
1101100 1101111 1110111`;

const outputStr = String.fromCharCode(
  ...binary.split(' ').map(bin => parseInt(bin, 2))
)

console.log(outputStr);
```

#### Edit 2:

As this answer gets more traffic over time, I am going to also add the solution to do it the other way around too ... just in case:

```js
const str = `StackOverflow`;

const outputStr = str.split('') // split in single chars
  .map(c => c.charCodeAt(0) // get the UTF-16 code (10 base)
             .toString(2)) // transform it back to a string (2 base)
  .join(' ') // make single string from array

console.log(outputStr);
```

Comment: Ok bro got everything but what does the code bin mean which is used in first example

Comment: @SubhaJeetSikdar `bin` is the name of the parameter for the function you pass to map. The function map takes an arrow function with one parameter which you can give any name you like. `bin` could essentially be called `someVariable` too. The variable itself represents one element from the array. The map function iterates over all elements of the array and applies the arrow function (`varName => parseInt(varName , 2)`) on each.

Comment: Bro what does the sign ` mean?

Comment: These are called [Template Literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals). Check them out, they are really useful in JavaScript. @SubhaJeetSikdar

Comment: NB: if you put Unicode characters through this you'll see binary numbers of up to 16 bits in length.

Answer (score 2):

```js
str ="01000001 01110010 01100101 01101110 00100111 01110100 00100000 01100010 01101111 01101110 01100110 01101001 01110010 01100101 01110011 00100000 01100110 01110101 01101110 00100001 00111111"
    
    
function binaryAgent(str) {
      return str.split(' ').map(letter=>String.fromCharCode(parseInt(letter, 2))).join('')
     
}
    
console.log(binaryAgent(str))
```

- First we use the .split() method to convert the string to array using the ' '(space character)
- After that we use the .map() high-order loop method to iterate through each binary-code-letter
- For each binary-code-letter we use String.fromCharCode() on parseInt('each letter',2)=> which converts the binary string to a number. The second argument "2" of the parseInt method which is called(radix) is to define which numeral system we want to use.
- Finally we can join the manipulated array back together calling the join('') method but this time we don't use a space between

=======

Comment: Please add some explanation for your answer so that audience can understand the working of the code

Comment: and also explain how it improves on the accepted answer (hint: it doesn't, because apart from wrapping into a function the code is identical apart from the variable names).

Answer (score 1):

```js
const binary = `1010011 1110100 1100001 1100011 1101011 
1001111 1110110 1100101 1110010 1100110 
1101100 1101111 1110111`;

const inputStr = binary.split(' ');
const output = [];
inputStr.forEach(item => {output.push(String.fromCharCode(parseInt(item, 2)))});
console.log(output.join(''));
```

Comment: downvote for using `forEach()` with a `push` instead of `.map` .   You've copied the accepted answer, and made it _worse_.

Comment: @Alnitak just an alternative. Makes sense to use map tho

Comment: using foreach/push instead of map is an _anti-pattern_.   There is no good reason for it, and it would be a down-mark in any code review.